# how to get all bins names for aerospike given set

Tags: java, scala, aerospike

I'm trying to retrieve all bins names for some aerospike set
I'm able to do that in command line bu executing

```
asinfo -v 'bins/<my_set_name>'
```

I'm looking for a Java/Scala code that can do the same
The aerospike client version I'm using is "3.1.6"

Answer (score 2):

You would have to scan the set and build a list of bins names for the set.

Also the info command you provided wouldn't work with a set name, it would need the namespace name. See [bins](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/info/#bins) in the command reference.

To execute the bins command in you client there should be an **info** API that would take the same input as the command line utility.

[Java client info API](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/Info.html)

Answer (score 1):

the correct way:

```
 val policy = new ClientPolicy()
 val client = new AerospikeClient(policy, initialHost, port)
 val node = client.getNodes
 val conn=node(0).getConnection(1000) 
 val info= new Info(conn,"bins/users")   
 val buff:Array[Byte]=info.getBuffer
 val buffStr=new String(buff)
```

buffStr contains the bins list at users namespace in Aersospike as string

Comment: This solution works for a namespace but not a set as the op requested. +1 for the namespace example though, could you clarify that in your answer? Also should note that the bin list for a namespace grows monotonically and is only reset by a server restart... so this command will also return bins that may be no longer in use. Though it is expensive, a namespace or set scan is the most accurate method to retrieve bin names in use.